# Is MongoDB _id unique by default?

Tags: mongodb

Is MongoDB _id unique by default, or do I have to set it to unique?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All documents contain an `_id` field. All collections (except for capped ones) automatically create unique index on `_id`.

Try this:

```
db.system.indexes.find()
```

Comment: Except capped collections.  There the index on _id is optional.  Woe be unto you if server is part of a replica set & you don't have unique _id's there though.  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-UsageandRestrictions

Comment: If it's unique by default, why does it not show "unique": true . Secondly, are objectId's on subdocuments and arrays automatically unique. granted, one has to manually create an index on an array field

Comment: @meffect: it's a special field and a special index. And no, uniqueness on fields other than `_id` is not automatically enforced, you have to create a unique index yourself.

Comment: for inserting unique array elements use $addtoset it inserts elemnt in an array if it is unique :)

Answer (score 21):

For the most part, _id in mongodb is unique enough. There is one edge case where it's possible to generate a duplicate id though:

If you generate more than (2^(3 * 8))-1 = 16,777,215 object ids in the same single second, you could get a duplicate id due to how object ids are generated, otherwise you are alright. If you did generate that many ids in the same second, you are in a lottery and have a 1 in 2^(5 * 8) chance on top of this to get your duplicate id.

Let me know if you ever manage to pull this off with a realistic use case. Apparently google only gets around 70,000 searches a second.

Here is my source: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb

ObjectID is a 96-bit number which is composed as follows:

- a 4-byte timestamp value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch (which will not run out of seconds until the year 2106)
- a 5-byte random value, and
- a 3-byte incrementing counter, starting with a random value.

---

Update: I have also heard the 5-byte random value could instead be replaced by 3 bytes representing the machine id and 2 bytes representing the process id.

Comment: This is the only real **correct** answer!

Comment: Thank you @Max, would you be so kind to elaborate on this 16,777,215 magic number?

Comment: It sounds like @Max is assuming your `_id` field is using one of the UUID formats that encodes both the time and process ID into it. Unfortunately, that is *not* the way an ObjectID is formed (it only uses time, the rest is random).

Furthermore, mongodb does force you to use an ObjectID or UUID for your ID field, it can be any valid mongodb type.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify a couple things.

Answer (score 4):

ok .. short version

`YES` `YES` `YES`

`_id uniqid by default` , mongoDB creates index on `_id` by default and you do not need any settings

Answer (score 3):

According to [MongoDB's manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#index-type-id) the answer is **yes, it's unique by default**:

> MongoDB creates the _id index, which is an ascending unique index on the _id field, for all collections when the collection is created. You cannot remove the index on the _id field.

Comment: Linked page doesn't describe `_id` as unique or ascending anymore.

Comment: The information about the unique `_id` index moved to: [std-label-index-type-id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#std-label-index-type-id)

Answer (score 0):

Share what I learned about this topic here:

Different from other RDBMS, Mongodb document's Id is generated on the client side. This functionality is usually implemented in the drivers of various programming languages.

The Id is string with 12 bytes length, which consists of several parts as follows:

`TimeStamp(4 bytes) + MachineId(3 bytes) + ProcessId(2 bytes) + Counter(3 bytes)`

Based on this pattern, it's extremely unlikely to have two Ids duplicated.