# Query with several Index fields in the query

Tags: java, mongodb

Consider this is my collection structure

```
"hotel":{
    "hotelType":"",
    "hotelname":"",
    "branchname":""
}
```

currently I have one index for _id

```
{
    "hotelType" : 1,
    "unique": false
}
```

My query is like

```
db.employee.find({"hotelname":"?", "branchname":"?", "hotelType":"?"});
```

Note: A Hotel can have as many branches

I am thinking of adding a compound index

```
{
    "hotelname" : 1,
    "branchname" : 1
}
```

Please let me know if this helps performance or fasten query

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks weird to me, why filter the `hotelname` and the `branchname` before the `_id` ? 
It's a nosense because your `_id` is unique. If you have it, just do a simple query like this :

```
db.employee.find({"_id":"?"});
```

In a MongoDB collection, the `_id` field is unique and created for all documents. So even if you put a (useless) index like this :

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "unique": false
}
```

It doesn't change the fact that the collection already has a unique index in this field.

Edit : take a look at this conversation : [Wonder: Is MongoDB _id unique by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932631/wonder-is-mongodb-id-unique-by-default)

Comment: Thanks, I  thought _id may not be unique if 1000's of data inserted in a second, I edited the question

Comment: I used explain() to find the usage of index, which i don't aware of it before