# Is _id field truly unique in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I probably would not ask if I have not seen this:

```js
> db.requests.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "name" : 1,
                },
                "name" : "name_1"
        }
]
```

Where `_id` index does not have `unique: true`. Can it mean that the `_id` index is somehow not truly unique or something? Can it behave differently (non-unique) if `_id` is populated with non-`ObjectId` values - some other fundamental types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wonder: Is MongoDB \_id unique by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932631/wonder-is-mongodb-id-unique-by-default)

Comment: @AlexisG Thanks. Yeah, pretty much. Though it is not clear why it is not `unique: true` in the index list.

Comment: It seems that `_id` is an exception, and the unique index is implicit

Comment: In practice: YES. In theory: NO, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Would you be so kind to elaborate?

Comment: See [Documents#_id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html#the-id-field) and [An exception when using as a shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/index.html#shard-key-indexes).

Comment: It's explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66181459/3027266) - the last, least rated answer.