# Can a Mongoose document's _id field change on save/create?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a question regarding any potential for collisions between Mongoose and Mongodb with respect to creating model instances/documents in application space and subsequently saving them.

Let's say I have a model "MyModel" and I do the following:

```
let appSpaceDocument = new MyModel({fieldA: "12", fieldB: "Jakarta"});
```

I get an application space document that has an _id field but has not yet been saved to mongodb.

Is there any guarantee that the _id field is unique and doesn't already exist in the specified collection? I understand that, if it's not unique, the _id field will create a collision whenever it's saved and will fail to be inserted, but is that something that happens or does Mongoose ensure that the _id field will be unique for the collection associated with that model?

I hope this question makes sense. I'm just trying to be thorough in understanding what potential issues could arise and how I would message the user in the event of such a collision.

Thanks!

Comment: mongo _id are 24 hexadecimal strings (24^16 possiblitities). I don't think you'll need to worry about collisions, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66181459/3462319)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is MongoDB \_id unique by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932631/is-mongodb-id-unique-by-default)

Comment: @depperm thanks for the responses. While I know the value will be unique once stored in mongodb (or will result in an index violation if it's not unique), what I'm not 100% certain of is whether or not it's guaranteed to be unique just by calling
"
new MyModel([with arguments]);
"
Because this code happens in application space, I'm not sure if Mongoose "knows" what IDs have been used/stored in the database already.