# MongoDb, inserting, _id and CQRS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cqrs

I'm writing an application in node.js using mongo as database. One of my use case is add object to the tree (whole data structure of this tree is store in mongo). So whole operation is quite simple: I create new document and get _id back, then I can use this _id and update parents children table. Ok cool it works. But I want write it better and achieve CQRS but insert operation like I describe above is not valid CQRS (inserting is command and retrieving _id is query). Unless I can specify _id so I don't need obtain it from mongo.

So my question is how I can generate unique _id. I don't want it to be random - it might happen that two random values will be the same.

Comment: You can specify your own `_id` value, it can be any type. Simplest way is to generate an integer value from a sequence. Or use `ObjectId()` to get an id explicitly before you insert the document. Why do you think it is "better" to use your own id?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Ok I just can't find in documentation that if I use `ObjectId()` to generate new id it will be unique.
Why I want to do that? So flow is that I insert new object, get the id, modify parent (in code) and then update parent (in database). So you have to operation with modify database (insert and update) with some logic in-between. This actually be separated like this: I create child _id modify parent (in code) then I save (ideally in one transaction) both - insert for child, update for parent - in database. This way I can have saving operation to database layer.

Comment: Yes, the `ObjectId()` will be unique, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932631/is-mongodb-id-unique-by-default  In theory it is possible that you don't get a unique ID, however this scenario is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks. I love this answar XD I think I won't try to break the system and try to generate "16,777,215 object ids in the same single second, while running in one process while on the same machine".

Answer (score 0):

Most MongoDB driver clients will include the `_id` field and generate an ObjectId before sending the insert operation to MongoDB. It also applies by default to node.js driver, see [insertOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.6/classes/Collection.html#insertOne):

> If documents passed in do not contain the `_id` field, one will be added to each of the documents missing it by the driver, mutating the document. This behavior can be overridden by setting the `forceServerObjectId` flag.

So, don't waste your time on that.